# Dynamically create helm values based on list

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

We're using [Airflow community helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/f5c2f0cd617982c642789cf66fdef48453f84e67/charts/airflow/values.yaml#L174) and I'm trying to create the pools dynamically based on a list of teams, so that I can re-use that teams list in different settings.

Note that these settings are in the same values.yaml file, but perhaps there's a more suitable way to make this happen of which I'm not aware.

`values.yaml:`

```
teams:
  - name: team1
    pool_slots: 4
  - name: team2
    pool_slots: 5

airflow:
  ...
  pools:
    # This part I want to create dynamically based on the list above
    - name: pool-team1
      slots: 4
    - name: pool-team2
      slots: 5
  ...
```

I tried the following options and ran the `helm template .. --values values.yaml` command, which gave the following errors:

`Option 1`
Error: "range can't iterate over {{- range $teams := .Values.teams }}"

```
teams:
  - name: team1
    pool_slots: 4
  - name: team2
    pool_slots: 5

airflow:
  ...
  pools:
    {{- range $team := .Values.teams}}
    - name: pool-{{ $team.name }}
      slots: {{ $team.pool_slots}}
    {{- end }}
  ...
```

`Option 2`
Error: "range can't iterate over {{- range .Values.teams}}"

```
teams:
  - name: team1
    pool_slots: 4
  - name: team2
    pool_slots: 5

airflow:
  ...
  pools:
    {{- range .Values.teams}}
    - name: pool-{{ $teams.name }}
      slots: {{ $teams.pool_slots}}
    {{- end }}
  ...
```

`Option 3`
Error: "error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 17: could not find expected ':' "

*Based on [How to pass helm values dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443335/how-to-pass-helm-values-dynamically)*

```
teams:
  - name: team1
    pool_slots: 4
  - name: team2
    pool_slots: 5

{{- $ := . -}}
{{- range $team := .Values.teams}}
airflow:
  ...
  pools:
    - name: pool-{{ $team.name }}
      slots: {{ $team.pool_slots}}
  ...
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Helm on its own can't do this.  If you can't edit the chart code, you'll need to use another tool to construct the values file.  In some contexts I use [Helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io) which does allow using the Helm templating language to construct values files, among other things; would that meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze! The configuration and deployment of the chart is done via Azure DevOps, We use `helm pull` to download the chart, so that would mean we would have to overwrite files in the downloaded chart with our own custom made files?